# get values out of array

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, arrays

Hi i'm searching for some help with the below piece of code. I would like to map and put the values in the SQL db. But I can't seem to get the values out of the array ttNieuweSessie.

So with a result that all values are undefined. Does someone have tips on how to get it working?

```
msg.topic = ttNieuweSessie.map(function(){
    return 'INSERT INTO tblSessies (idSessie, BeginTijdms, idApparaat) VALUES ('+idSessie+', '+BeginTijdms+', '+idApparaat+') ';
});
```

Comment: .map() executes the funtion you specified for every element in the array. you can specify a parameter in you function to get acces to this element, but it would still return the querystring for every element and not one string with all parameters. how are the values stored in the array?

Comment: They are stored like this:                                                       
ttNieuweSessie.push({
            idSessie: id,
            BeginTijdms: myObject[i].Tijdms,
            idApparaat: myObject[i].idApparaat
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a parameter to the function you specified as callback for [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get acces to the `currentValue`.

```
var queries = ttNieuweSessie.map(function(val){
        return 'INSERT INTO tblSessies (idSessie, BeginTijdms, idApparaat) VALUES ('+val.idSessie+', '+val.BeginTijdms+', '+val.idApparaat+') ';
});
```

Then your `queries` variable contains an array with a query for every element in `ttNieuweSessie`

Answer (score 0):

```
    msg.topic = ttNieuweSessie.map(function(value){
       return 'INSERT INTO tblSessies (idSessie, BeginTijdms, idApparaat) VALUES ('+value.idSessie+', '+value.BeginTijdms+', '+value.idApparaat+') '; 
    })
```

You can pass current value to function in [map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)